# How to replace a certain path from the PATH variable?

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin, path

I am using Cygwin and would like to modify the following PATH via bash shell:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VSTSDB/Deploy:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/BIN:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/Tools:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319:/cygdrive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/VCPackages:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/HTML Help Workshop:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python33:/cygdrive/c/_WORK/java/jdk1.6.0_30/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Roxio Shared/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Roxio Shared/10.0/DLLShared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WIDCOMM/Bluetooth Software:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/WIDCOMM/Bluetooth Software/syswow64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/apache-ant-1.8.3/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Code Collaborator Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon
```

The path is huge.

Somewhere in the middle there is
`c/_WORK/java/jdk1.6.0_30/bin`.

What I'd like to do is to temporarily replace this with
`c/_WORK/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin`

In other words, I'd like to use different Java SDK versions. Sometimes I would use 1.6 sometimes 1.7.

How would I change the Java SDK path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, customize the variable by running these commands:

```
PATH="path_to_your_jdk_bin_dir:$PATH"
export PATH
```

The new path will take precedence over the other one. To make this change permanent in your profile, put these two lines to the `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` file.

Further, I would recommend to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate a little bit? Have in mind that the system is shared, so I cannot do much on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle different versions of the Java VM installed on your machine via cygwin is to register them in the `alternatives` system. Check its manpage for details.

This defines the system-wide default selected JRE/JDK.

To override this in a per-user environment, include `JAVA_HOME` in their `.bash_profile`.